# DOM has not loaded | What to do?

Tags: php, javascript, html

The PHP snippet in the code below creates a div with id universals.

However in the javascript further down when I try to access this value I get null.  Obviously the PHP is generated server side.  So I would have thought that the data would be available by the time the script runs on the client.

What can I do to fix?

Comment: The PHP code is irrelevant. Show us the generated HTML & JavaScript.

Comment: Make sure the generated markup contains what you think it contains. If it doesnt, find out why. If it does, check your JavaScript. That's all we can tell you from your question body.

Comment: there is nothing else to add...i put in the generated HTML for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: If your function is self-executing (you didn't show that part), it should work, as you can see on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPj5a/).

Comment: @Hiro No, echoing the div from PHP or adding it to the HTML directly shouldn't make any difference here. I asked about the IIFE because we're running out of options here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an onload in the body. 
Add this after your body

```
onload="whateverfunction()"
```

Comment: as in <body onload="whatever()">